# Call a function at both onchange and page load event

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I want to call a function at both `onchange` event and page load for edit page. This is my select tag, here I call a function on `onchange` event but I want to call this function on page load.

```
<div class="input-group">                                        
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-edit fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
<?php foreach ($get_institute as $get_institutes) { ?>
    <select name="state_name" class="form-control" id="state_id" onchange="change_state(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);
                stateName();
                document.getElementById('selected_text').value = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text" style="width: 100%;">
            <?php foreach ($get_state as $get_states) { ?>
                <?php if ($get_states['id'] == $get_institutes['state_id']) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $get_states['id']; ?>" selected><?php echo $get_states['name']; ?></option> 
            <?php } else { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $get_states['id']; ?>"><?php echo $get_states['name']; ?></option>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="state" id="state">
</div>
```

This is my function

```
<script>
    function change_state(state_id) {        
        if (state_id == "Select") {
            $("#city_id").html("<option>Select</option>");
            $("#city_id").trigger("chosen:updated");
            $("#city_id").trigger("liszt:updated");
        } else {
         loadData(state_id);          
        }
    }
    function loadData(state_id) {      
        var dataString = 'state_id=' + state_id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?
            >admin/select_city_by_state_id",
            data: dataString,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {              
                $("#city_id").html("<option>Select</option>");
                $("#city_id").append(result);
                $("#city_id").trigger("chosen:updated");
                $("#city_id").trigger("liszt:updated");
            }
        });
    }
    window.onload = change_state;
</script>
<script>
function stateName() {       
    var label1 = document.getElementById('state_id')
    [document.getElementById('state_id').selectedIndex].innerHTML;        
  $('#state').val(label1);
}    
window.onload = stateName;
</script>
```

Here I use `window.onload`, but my function does not load.

Comment: `POST` is an inappropriate request method when _reading_ data from the server side.  `POST` is for _writing_ and `GET` is for _reading_. There are some times when `POST` _can_ be appropriate, but this is not one.  Use `"admin/select_city_by_state_id/" + state_id`

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
window.onload = change_state; //remove this
```

Use it as

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    change_state();
});
</script>
```

Comment: i also tried this way but function not call on page load.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to remove onchange event from select dropdown.

```
 <select name="state_name" class="form-control" id="state_id">
```

Then add that function and call onload and as well as onchange:

```
function change_state() {        
    var sel = document.getElementById("state_id");
    var text= sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
  if (state_id == "Select") {
        $("#city_id").html("<option>Select</option>");
        $("#city_id").trigger("chosen:updated");
        $("#city_id").trigger("liszt:updated");
  } else {
    loadData(state_id);          
  }
}


document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  change_state();
});

$('#state_id').change(function() {
  change_state();
});
```